# sas- rank inside a macro

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I'm trying to do a loop over a liststo perform ranks for several variables.

And then I do the loop with:

```
options mprint;
%macro ranks(listado);
%let count=%sysfunc(countw(&listado));/*counw= count words in a string*/
%do i=1 %to &count;
%put 'count' &count;
    %let vari=%qscan(&listado,&i,%str(,));
    %put 'vari' &vari;

    proc rank data=labo2.J_tabla_modelo groups=10  out=labo2.tmp;
      var &vari.;
      ranks rk_&vari.;
    run;
%end;
%mend;

        %ranks(%str(G_MERGE6_t1_monto6,A_CLI_monto_sucursal_1,A_CLI_monto_sucursal_2,
A_CLI_monto_sucursal_3, A_CLI_monto_sucursal_4,A_M_0705_monto));
```

I get the following error:

> ```
> ERROR: Number of VAR statement variables was not equal  to the number of RANKS statement variables.
> ```

Don't know how to solve it. Because if I run the code written by the macro works.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, don't do the macro loop this way.  It's messy.  Generate a list of macro calls.

Second, you're not really wanting to do that either, here.  What you need to generate is this:

```
proc rank data=whatever out=whatever;
  var v1 v2 v3 v4;
  ranks r_v1 r_v2 r_v3 r_v4;
run;
```

What you are generating is a bunch of different PROC RANKs, which isn't ideal.

How I'd do it:

```
data my_vars;
  length vari $32;
  input vari $;
  datalines;
G_MERGE6_t1_monto6
A_CLI_monto_sucursal_1
A_CLI_monto_sucursal_2
A_CLI_monto_sucursal_3
A_CLI_monto_sucursal_4
A_M_0705_monto
;;;;
run;

proc sql;
 select cats('r_',vari) 
   into :ranklist separated by ' '
   from my_vars;
 select vari 
   into :varlist separated by ' '
   from my_vars;
quit;

proc rank data=whatever out=whatever groups=10;
  var &varlist;
  rank &ranklist;
run;
```

If you actually do need the individual `PROC RANK` calls, then you need to figure out how to deal with the output, and then do a similar approach.

(Also, odds are that first datastep isn't needed-  you probably have that data somewhere, like in dictionary.columns).

Comment: ok you are right. But since I already have the columns names, I tried this: **proc sql; select cats('r_', name) into: lista_rank separated by ' ' from dictionary.columns where libname='LABO2' AND MEMNAME='J_TABLA_MODELO' and name like '%monto%'; quit;** but I get: **Apparent symbolic reference LISTA_RANK not resolved.**

Comment: sounds like your PROC SQL didn't correctly work.  Name is probably upper case, for one, though I think LIKE should not care about that.

Comment: It's not that because this one : **proc sql; select name into: lista_monto separated by ' ' from dictionary.columns where libname='LABO2' AND MEMNAME='J_TABLA_MODELO' and name like '%monto%'; quit;**  is working. **Maybe something related to the cats??? don't know.**

Comment: No, nothing wrong with the CATS.  Does it put a list to your output window of the r_variables?